# How to read a parameter in a Vapor middleware without consuming it

Tags: vapor, server-side-swift

I am brand new to the Vapor framework, and am trying to protect multiple routes. Basically, I want to make sure that all routes under `/campaigns/:id` can only be accessed if the user actually has access to that particular campaign with that ID. So that I can't just enter any ID into the url and access any campaign.

Now, instead of adding logic for this to every single route (already 6 so far), I figured I'd use a middleware for this. This is what I came up with so far, with the help of some friendly folk over at the Vapor Discord:

```swift
final class CampaignMiddleware: Middleware {
  func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
    let user = try request.requireAuthenticated(User.self)
    return try request.parameters.next(Campaign.self).flatMap(to: Response.self) { campaign in
      guard try campaign.userID == user.requireID() else {
        throw Abort(.forbidden, reason: "Campaign doesn't belong to you!")
      }
      return try next.respond(to: request)
    }
  }
}

struct CampaignController: RouteCollection {
  func boot(router: Router) throws {
    let route = router.grouped("campaigns")

    let tokenAuthMiddleware = User.tokenAuthMiddleware()
    let guardMiddleware = User.guardAuthMiddleware()
    let tokenAuthGroup = route.grouped(tokenAuthMiddleware, guardMiddleware)

    tokenAuthGroup.get(use: getAllHandler)
    tokenAuthGroup.post(CampaignCreateData.self, use: createHandler)

    // Everything under /campaigns/:id/*, CampaignMiddleware makes sure that the campaign actually belongs to you
    let campaignRoute = tokenAuthGroup.grouped(Campaign.parameter)
    let campaignMiddleware = CampaignMiddleware()
    let protectedCampaignRoute = campaignRoute.grouped(campaignMiddleware)

    protectedCampaignRoute.get(use: getOneHandler)
    protectedCampaignRoute.delete(use: deleteHandler)
    protectedCampaignRoute.put(use: updateHandler)

    // Add /campaigns/:id/entries routes
    let entryController = EntryController()
    try protectedCampaignRoute.register(collection: entryController)
  }

  func getAllHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[Campaign]> {
    let user = try req.requireAuthenticated(User.self)
    return try user.campaigns.query(on: req).all()
  }

  func getOneHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Campaign> {
    return try req.parameters.next(Campaign.self)
  }

  // ...deleted some other route handlers...
}
```

The problem here is that the middleware is "eating up" the campaign parameter by doing `request.parameters.next(Campaign.self)`. So in `getOneHandler`, where it *also* tries to access `req.parameters.next(Campaign.self)`, it fails with error "Insufficient parameters". Which makes sense, since `.next` actually removes that param from the internal array of parameters.

Now, how can I write a middleware, that uses the parameter, without eating it up? Do I need to use the raw values and query the Campaign model myself? Or can I somehow reset the parameters after using `.next`? Or is there another better way to deal with model authorization in Vapor 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heeey, it looks like you could get your `Campaign` from request without dropping it like this

```swift
guard let parameter = req.parameters.values.first else {
    throw Abort(.forbidden)
}
try Campaign.resolveParameter(parameter.value, on: req)
```

So your final code may look like

```swift
final class CampaignMiddleware: Middleware {
  func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> Future<Response> {
    let user = try request.requireAuthenticated(User.self)
    guard let parameter = request.parameters.values.first else {
        throw Abort(.forbidden)
    }
    return try Campaign.resolveParameter(parameter.value, on: request).flatMap { campaign in
      guard try campaign.userID == user.requireID() else {
        throw Abort(.forbidden, reason: "Campaign doesn't belong to you!")
      }
      return try next.respond(to: request)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Some mixed usage of request / req in your answer but once fixed, it works great.